# Can we add or conditional operator in ngClass ?

Tags: angular

I want to evaluate multiple condition in ngClass, following is the my code

```
[ngClass]="{'has-warning':expression1 && expression2,'has-danger':(expression3 && expression4) || expression5 || (expression6  && expression7) || expression8}"
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your `ngClass`. It should work. Could you create a jsfiddle to showcase the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can you `[ngClass]` with multiple conditions, although I would recommend putting the logic into the component class, as indicates the [Angular's Style Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#05-17)

> Do put presentation logic in the Component class, and not in the
>   template.

Check the plunker to see the example:

```
<label [ngClass]="{'yellow': isRedChecked && isGreenChecked, 'red': isRedChecked && !isGreenChecked, 'green': isGreenChecked && !isRedChecked}">Conditional Style 1</label>

<label [ngClass]="getClassName()">Conditional Style 2</label>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/nC2XdNP2arIyUCjCGTKH